# Is there a way to make every file have a default script with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

So let's say I have four files: `index.html`, `aboutus.html`, `index.js`, and `contact.php`, and I want all these files to have the same script (`index.js`) with `.htaccess` I was thinking something like:

```
AddDefaultScript index.js
```

But that doesn't work and I didn't expect it to work, but I wanted to try either way. Is there any way for each and every one of these files have the same script? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I've also tried this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.js
```

But nothing :/

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. What does " I want all these files to have the same script" mean? What does "have" here mean?

Comment: Bit of a guess, but it sounds like you perhaps want to include `index,js` as a linked script in each of those `.html` and `.php` files? Although a further confusion here is that you also gave `index.js` as one of the files you want to "have the same script"?! But if that is what you mean then this isn't something that `.htaccess` does? Maybe you're talking about a front-controller pattern? Are you wanting to send all requests to `index.js`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.js
RewriteRule index\.html|aboutus\.html|contact\.php index.js [L]
```

All requests to index.html, aboutus.html and contact.php will run index.js.

Comment: I'll be sure to try that.